# Clojure Specter: Pass complete entry path to walker()

Tags: clojure, specter

I am using Nathan Marz's wonderful [Specter](https://github.com/nathanmarz/specter) library. I am doing syntax tree transformations with it, among other things. Suppose that there is a nested data structure:

```
 (def expr  
  '([:var price (5)]
    [:var output ("")]
    (clojure.core/cond
        (< price 4)
        [:var output ("6")]
        (= price 5)
        [:var output ("==")]
        :else
        [:var output ("7")])))
```

I can apply a transformation to all `:var` nodes via:

```
(transform [(walker #(and (sequential? %1) (= :var (first %1))))] 
           transform-fn expr)
```

However, i'd like to pass the complete path of the navigated-to node to `transform-fn`, so that to distinguish between parent `:var` entries and nested ones.

More generally, the action of `transform-fn` should depend on the complete path of the node being operated on. In a sense, this is similar to inserting `VAL` for each node visited by `walker`. How can this be achieved?

Thanks!